# Bash script to backup server upload folders

Tags: regex, bash, ssh, sed

I have a CentOS server running WHM/cPanel sites, and a lot of these sites run WordPress.  I would like to do an automated backup that zips and moves any account containing an 'uploads' folder into a backup directory.  I know there are other solutions, but most want you to backup the entire WordPress site, I only need to backup the uploads however.

I'm not very good with .sh scripts and have spent a lot of time already trying to figure this out, but I can't seem to find any examples similar enough for me to be successful.  The main problem I have is naming the zip after the account.

Location of most upload folders (user1 being the account that changes):

`/home/user1/public_html/wp-content/uploads
/home/user2/public_html/wp-content/uploads
/home/user3/public_html/wp-content/uploads`

Script example:

`` find /home/ -type d -name uploads -exec sh -c  'zip -r /backup/uploads/alluploads.zip `dirname $0`/`basename $0`' {} \; ``

The problem with this approach is that it all writes to one single zip file.  How can I alter this to save each users uploads to there own user1-uploads.zip file?

I've played around with exec and sed but I can't seem to figure it out.  This is the best I got - just trying to get it to echo the name - but it's not right. Sorry, I'm terrible with regex:

`` find /home/ -type d -name uploads -exec sh -c  'string=`dirname $0` echo $string | sed `/\/home\/\(.*\)\/new\/wp-content\/uploads/`'{} \; ``

Would appreciate any help or directions on how to fix this.  Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be your first question on stack overflow.  Kudos on clarity, conciseness and code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of solutions come to mind, you could loop through the user directories:

```
cd /home
for udir in *; do
   find /home/$udir -type d -name uploads -exec sh -c 'zip -r /backup/uploads/'"$udir"'-uploads.zip `dirname $0`/`basename $0`' {} \;
done
```

or use `cut` to get the second element of the path:

```
find /home/ -type d -name uploads -exec sh -c 'zip -r /backup/uploads/`echo "$0" | cut -d/ -f 2`-uploads.zip `dirname $0`/`basename $0`' {} \;
```

Although both of these would run into issues if the user has more than 1 directory anywhere under their home that is named `uploads`

You might use tr to simply replace the path separator with another character so you end up with a separate zip for each `uploads` directory:

```
find /home/ -type d -name uploads -exec sh -c 'zip -r /backup/uploads/`echo $0 | tr "/" "-"`.zip `dirname $0`/`basename $0`' {} \;
```

so  you would end up wil files named `/backup/uploads/home-user-wp-content-uploads.zip` and `/backup/uploads/home-user-wip-uploads.zip` instead of one zip overwriting the other

Comment: Thanks for this - I like the idea of replacing the slashes with dashes so then it's really obvious where the backup was located in case it's not in the normal location.  Is there an easy way to get rid of the first dash before home, I'm getting it saved as `/backup/uploads/-home-user-wp-content-uploads.zip` because of the first slash in /home/ - otherwise it's perfect for my needs.

Comment: you could `cd /` and `find home .....` then there would not be a leading slash, or replace `tr "/" "-"` with `sed -e "s=^/==;s=/=-=g"` to remove the leading slash

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bash's globbing with `*` to expand all the different user directories.

```
for uploads in /home/*/public_html/wp-content/uploads; do
    IFS=/ read -r _ _ user _ <<<"$uploads"
    zip -r /backup/uploads/${user}.zip "$uploads"
done
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution as well, exactly what I asked for.